# Connection with MySQL database on any other pc! Python

Tags: python, mysql

I made programm but it gives me error
"Access denied for user acer: using PASWORD "yes""
This happend when I run my program on another pc, it means  that database does not exist on this pc . how I program my App to connect to the MySQL database  on any other pc that doesn't have preior instalation of Mysql?

Do I have to create a new MySQL database that matches my database password and name for every pc by myself ?

Comment: This error does not mean that a database does not exists. It literally means that your user name or password is incorrect or your user does not have acces.

Comment: I know, but when I check on databases it does not exist. So do I need to create one for each pc ?

Comment: I can't answer this question as it depends on your business requirements.

Comment: I work on pc that are offline, not connected to the internet!! I just want to know how to connect or establish a connection to mysql database when running my app on a new pc because my app is already programmed with a database name and password ?